# Drupal 7 content type summarisation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7 how to  display a tile of all node count of a content type.
some thing like this  but both should be in separate tiles  like a tile for poc and a tile for poc2.

[image]

Comment: Use views module...make custom view for that.

Comment: @MilanG you meant tweak view

Comment: I mean you should create new view (view in Drupal's terminology, not some template file or something).

Comment: @MilanG  hi . i have a doubt  
                               $form['#submit'][]='hello_showHelloForm_submit';
                               return $form;

}     i was watching a youtube video to implement some button action so .. my question is why '$form['#submit'][]' why use  multidimensional array for this

Comment: More than one submit handler can be called. You can also attach your own by altering the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created it by custom module with the help of bootstrap